# Region area with double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, area

I need to find the area $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 < 2x < y < 3-x^2\}$ as the double integral $\int(\int dx) dy$.

I came up with:

$$\int_0^2\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}y}dxdy + \int_2^3\int_0^\sqrt{3-y}= \int_0^2\frac{1}{2}ydy + \int_2^3\sqrt{3-y}dy = \frac{1}{2}\frac{y^2}{2}\biggr\rvert^2_0 + \frac{2}{3}(3-y)^\frac{3}{2}\biggr\rvert_2^3 = \frac{1}{3}$$

But the solution gives $\frac{5}{3}$. I'm around this exercise a couple hours now and I can't seem to find my mistake.

Comment: $ \int_2^3 (3-y)^{\frac12} dy = -\frac 23(3-y)^{\frac 32}|_2^3.$  Note the sign change

Comment: @DougM Oh my, it was it! So silly of me. I can't believe it! Thank you very much

Comment: Should I delete the question or should I let it stay here?

Answer (score 2):

The correct splitting of the area into twois : the first one $A_1:=\{0\leq x\leq y/2\;,0\leq y\leq 2\}$, and the second one $A_2:=\{2\leq y\leq 3-x^2\;,0\leq x\leq 1\}$. So
$$A=A_1+A_2=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{y/2}\;dxdy+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{2}^{3-x^2}\;dydx=1+\frac{2}{3}=\frac{5}{3}$$

Comment: But why is the second area different from mine? I'm going "horizontally" from $y = 2$ to $y = 3$; that top rounded part. That's why the limits of the inner integral go from $0$ to $\sqrt{3-y}$. Shouldn't it be the same area either as I go horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Your second integral is also okay, but you have a mistake in the calculation

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is almost correct.

You made a single error when you took the antiderivative of the second integreal.

It should be $- \frac{2}{3}(3-y)^\frac{3}{2}\biggr\rvert_2^3 $ not $+ \frac{2}{3}(3-y)^\frac{3}{2}\biggr\rvert_2^3 $

That will give you the correct result of $\frac{5}{3}$.